# Inverse of a symmetric matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

An inverse of a real symmetric matrix should in theory return a real symmetric matrix (the same is valid for Hermitian matrices). However, when I compute the inverse with numpy or scipy the returned matrix is asymmetric. I understand that this is due to numerical error.

What is the best way to avoid this asymmetry? I want it to be valid mathematically, in order that it does not propagate the error further when I use it in my computations.

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
a =np.random.rand(n, n)
a_symm = (a+a.T)/2

a_symm_inv = np.linalg.inv(a_symm)

if (a_symm_inv == a_symm_inv.T).all():
    print("Inverse of matrix A is symmetric") # This does not happen!
else:
    print("Inverse of matrix A is asymmetric")
    print("Max. asymm. value: ", np.max(np.abs((a_symm_inv-a_symm_inv.T)/2)))
```

**EDIT**

This is my solution to the problem:

```
math_symm = (np.triu_indices(len(a_symm_inv), 1))
a_symm_inv[math_symm]=np.tril(a_symm_inv, -1).T[math_symm]
```

Comment: The problem is this line: `if (a_symm_inv == a_symm_inv.T).all():`. Arithmetic on floating point numbers is not exact. Thus you should not try to compare them for exact equality.

Comment: I understand that computation with floating point numbers is not exact. But I would like that the result is symmetric. In example rewriting the upper triangle with the lower triangle of the matrix.

Comment: But then I don't understand your problem. Since you know the result is a symmetric matrix, and you want to force float equality (which probably does not make too much sense), you can just overwrite the lower triangular matrix with the values of the upper.

Comment: `I want it to be valid mathematically`. You cannot calculate the exact inverse with a real computer. There are several numerical algorithms that approximate the inverse. I think you are overthinking this. The error stems from the limitation of float arithmetic of your computer. In a perfect world, you have your processor with infinite accuracy, and you get a perfect result :)

Comment: look at my answer - all close is what you want

Comment: @blaz: Maybe there's a very specific reason you want your matrix to keep the symmetry property, but if your focus is in numerical accuracy, you're not getting more precise results with your way. You're just preferring the errors of the upper triangular matrix. AFAIK, your request doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree with all the replies. The error is expected from a numerical point of view. As @cd98 mentioned I preffer the error of the upper triangular matrix. I was just thinking that there was maybe already something implemented in numpy that recognizes the symmetry of the matrix and therefore computes just the lower (or upper) triangle of an inverse matrix and copies it to the other. Looks faster to me.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you, this inverse is symmetric. Unluckily for you you can't compare floating points this way:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> n = 1000
>>> a =np.random.rand(n, n)
>>> a_symm = (a+a.T)/2
>>> 
>>> a_symm_inv = np.linalg.inv(a_symm)
>>> a_symm_inv_T = a_symm_inv.T
>>> print a_symm_inv[2,1]
0.0505944152801
>>> print a_symm_inv_T[2,1]
0.0505944152801
>>> print a_symm_inv[2,1] == a_symm_inv_T[2,1]
False
```

Luckily for you, you can use numpy all close to solve this problem  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html

```
>>> np.allclose(a_symm_inv, a_symm_inv_T)
True
```

Looks like its your lucky day

Edit: Wow, I am quite surprised cels answer looks to be faster than this:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = """import numpy as np
... a = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
... b = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
... def cool_comparison_function(matrix1, matrix2):
...     epsilon = 1e-9
...     if (np.abs(matrix1 - matrix2) < epsilon).all():
...             return True
...     else:
...             return False
... """
>>> timeit.Timer("cool_comparison_function(a,b)",setup).repeat(1, 1000)
[2.6709160804748535]
>>> timeit.Timer("np.allclose(a,b)",setup).repeat(1, 1000)
[11.295115947723389]
```

Comment: I think the inverse of a symmetric matrix is always symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

This simple change should convince you, that the inverse is indeed a symmetric matrix. Not mathematically, but at least numerically - that is up to a small error threshold epsilon

```
n = 1000
a =np.random.rand(n, n)
a_symm = (a+a.T)/2

a_symm_inv = np.linalg.inv(a_symm)
epsilon = 1e-9
if (np.abs(a_symm_inv - a_symm_inv.T) < epsilon).all():
    print("Inverse of matrix A is symmetric")
else:
    print("Inverse of matrix A is asymmetric")
    print("Max. asymm. value: ", np.max(np.abs((a_symm_inv-a_symm_inv.T)/2)))
```

Which outputs:

```
Inverse of matrix A is symmetric
```

Comment: use numpy all close - its better than doing this and does pretty much exactly the same thing

Comment: @user3684792 I don't see why it should be `better`. It hides the fact, that we are working with an epsilon.

Comment: you are correct, I profiled them both and numpy was slower by a factor 4. Check it out